# JTable Row Selection - No event fired and no blue color shown

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable which only allows row selection using a ListSelectionListener as shown in the below code snippet.  There are two problems in the JTable:

Q1) Although I set the first row selected by default  using the setSelectionRow method,  the related listSelection event is not fired when the program is started. The event is only fired if I click on another row but not the the first row - What do you think I should do to fix this considering the below code?

Q2) When I select a row, it isn't colored in blue in JTable. I noticed this started to happen after I introduced ListSelectionListener to the JTable's selection model. Before adding the listener, the table was making this color business when I selected a row - What do you think I should do to fix this considering the below code snippet? Thanks a lot.

```
     jTableBookings = new javax.swing.JTable();

     jTableBookings.setModel(new MyBookingTableModel(bookingTableData));
     jTableBookings.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
     jTableBookings.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
     jTableBookings.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);

     jTableBookings.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
     initColumnSizesForMinaBokBokningarJTable(jTableBookings);

     //QUESTION 1
     //Set selected row to first row for inital load.
     if (jTableBookings.getModel().getRowCount() > 0) {
         jTableBookings.setRowSelectionInterval(0, 0);
     }

     //QUESTION 2
     jTableBookings.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new   ListSelectionListener() {
     public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
           int sel = jTableBookings.getSelectedRow();
           fillBookingRecordFields(sel); //Here we do some business logic based on the selected row
     }
    });

    jScrollPane9.setViewportView(jTableBookings);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) [myTable.changeSelection(row, column, false, false);](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#changeSelection%28int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean%29)

2) disable setCellSelectionEnabled() and setColumnSelectionAllowed(), then works

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

class SelectedColumnTest {

    private JTableHeader header;
    private Object selectedColumn = null;
    private String[] columnNames = {"String", "Integer", "Boolean"};
    private Object[][] data = {{"aaa", 12, true}, {"bbb", 5, false}, {"CCC", 92, true}};
    private TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        }
    };
    private JTable table = new JTable(model);

    public JComponent makeUI() {
        //table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        //table.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
        //table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        table.changeSelection(0, 0, false, false);
        return p;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new SelectedColumnTest().makeUI());
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```